# Is there any way to revert single file using libgit2sharp?

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

I am using `libgit2sharp` in c# to get Modified/Deleted/Added files in git working directory and i have done this.

But i want to revert locally changed file in git working directory with the help of `libgit2sharp`, so how can i do this.?

Comment: By _"revert"_, do you mean you want to check out the file at specific revision?

Comment: No i just want to Revert/Undo modified files in working directory (Not committed).

Answer (score 4):

this is my implementation of undo changes of uncommited file:

```
    public void DiscardFileChanges(string filePath)
    {
        var options = new CheckoutOptions { CheckoutModifiers = CheckoutModifiers.Force };
        _repository.CheckoutPaths(_repository.Head.FriendlyName, new[] { filePath }, options);
    }
```

Explanation: You must checkout on a current branch with `--force` flag. This course reset your file to commitet version.

Notice that, when your file has status Added, You must remove this file manually.

Comment: This will also revert staged changes in that file. How to prevent that?

Comment: @Extrawurst need to use patches. You need to generate patch only with changes that you need and apply it.

Comment: @Andrew_STOP_RU_WAR_IN_UA How to apply this patch? Can you add an answer for this please

Comment: @JoJ because of some problems with libgit2 I have used terminal git to apply patches.  "git apply patchPath.txt" or sth like this

Comment: Okay thank you for the answer. This will not work for us, as we can't ensure GIT is always installed on the end system.

Comment: looking into my gitui code I can't find the problem of this anymore. regular checkout works. leaves staged changes untouched even for files in "added" status

Comment: @Andrew_STOP_RU_WAR_IN_UA There is a way to archive it with Lib2Git. The function is called: git_checkout_index

Comment: @Extrawurst You should recheck your code. Lib2GitSharp is also resetting the Index currently with a Checkout. The only solution we found so far is making use of the Proxy function `git_checkout_index` directly.